# Getting invalid character error when deleting a gridview row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I was assigned to convert some .Net projects in old version to to .net 4.0 version. I used ODAC driver replacing ODBC driver. Everything went fine until I found a problem with a gridview were I get illegal character Oracle exception when I try to delete a row. The gridview is inside an update panel. The exception I receive is Microsoft Jscript run time error:Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: ORA-00911:invalid character. The following is the code for the grid view and the sqldatasource. The linkbutton triggers the delete using the deleteparameters of the sqldatasource.

```
                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />   

                <Columns>



               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">

                   <ItemTemplate>

                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CODE_OWNER_ID", "default.aspx?id={0}") %>'>View</asp:HyperLink>



                    </ItemTemplate>

               </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE_OWNER_ID" Visible ="False" HeaderText="CODE OWNER ID" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE_TYPE"  ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText="CODE TYPE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="CODE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="UNIT_CODE"  ReadOnly ="True" HeaderText="UNIT CODE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="UNIT_NAME" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="UNIT NAME" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="UNIT_DO" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="UNIT DO" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="OWNER" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER_EMAIL" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="OWNER EMAIL" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER_PHONE" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="OWNER PHONE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER_MAILPOINT" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="OWNER MAILPOINT" />





               <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE_ESTABLISHED_DATE" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"   HeaderText="CODE ESTABLISHED DATE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_REVIEW_DATE" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"    HeaderText="LAST REVIEW DATE" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="REVIEW_USERNAME" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="REVIEW USERNAME" />

               <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE_DELETED_DATE" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"    HeaderText="CODE DELETED DATE" />   

               <asp:BoundField DataField="DELETE_REASON" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="DELETE REASON" />  

               <asp:BoundField DataField="UPDATE_USERNAME" ReadOnly="True"   HeaderText="UPDATE USERNAME" />    







                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

                         <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"

                            Text='Delete'



                                 OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');"

                                 CommandArgument='<%# bind("CODE_OWNER_ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>



                        </ItemTemplate>

                      <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />

                 </asp:TemplateField>



                </Columns>

                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="Navy" Font-Bold="True" />

                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" />

                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />

                </asp:GridView>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>

            <asp:PostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnAdd" />

        </Triggers>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;



            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sqldatasource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn_Code_Owner %>"

                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn_Code_Owner.ProviderName %>"



                 OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"

                  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM CODE_OWNER"

                  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID = ?"




                  OnSelecting="_data_Selecting"

                 ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" >



                    <DeleteParameters>

                        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_CODE_OWNER_ID" Type="Decimal"/>

                    </DeleteParameters>






            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Don't see a reason for that error yet.  Can you post the full exception details?

Comment: Hey christopher. The error do not have a stack trace. Visual studio points to a runtime internal file called ScriptResource.axd. It contain a lot of js functions. The error is showing on a function called Sys$Webforms$PageRequestmanager$_endPostback(error,executor,data). The delete parameter is a  primary key. I am getting the same error in most of the places were a gridview uses a delete link button. It works fine in ODBC.

Comment: Can you try to disable ajax on the Update panel and you should get a better error message.

Comment: Okay. Now I get the below message. Same Oracle error with a Stack trace
Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
Stack Trace: 
[OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00911: invalid character].

Comment: However the gridview is displaying all the data. But only when I click the delete link button this error shows up.

Comment: Okay now it should be easier to debug.  Use breakpoints right before the DB call and check the inputs for invalid characters.  Double check your datatypes for each column in your Stored Procedure if that is what you are using.  If it still looks good then try to run the same SQL command on the DB to see if you get more details as to what param is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But there is no input from user for this deletion. Also there is no code behind for this on the vb page. The deletion is done by using the primary key of the same table. I still think that there is something else making the trouble. Because I did not do anything to this code other than replacing it with Oracle driver.

Comment: By the way the deletion is working fine when I try the query using sqldeveloper. DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID = 3 an example

Comment: The datatype of the primary key is 'number' in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy alternative using row-deleting event of the grid-view. I Just removed the delete parameters in the sqldatasource of  asp page and then I set conflict-detection to overwrite-changes.

```
    Sqldatasource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM code_owner WHERE code_owner_ID = :original_code_owner_ID"
    Sqldatasource1.DeleteParameters.Add("original_code_owner_ID", GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values("code_owner_ID").ToString)
    Sqldatasource1.Delete()
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and wrap it w/ a Begin and End

```
BEGIN CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID = ? END
```

http://www.lazyasscoder.com/Article.aspx?id=89&title=ora-00911%3A+invalid+character+when+executing+multiple+Oracle+SQL+statements

Comment: Hey, that sounded like a solution. But when I try BEGIN DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID =? END I got the following error ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 1, column 55:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

  ;

Comment: When I try BEGIN DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID =? END; I got Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 1, column 56:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

  begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
  null pragma raise return select update while with
  <an identifier> <a double-quoted d

Comment: BEGIN DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID =? ; END; I get invalid character error

Comment: Make sure there is a space between the "=" and the "?".  Other than that I am out of ideas man.

Comment: okay. That also not worked. My boss don't want to know the sql exception. She just want to finish it in time. Only we know the difficulty :-)

Comment: You could try to hard code the delete command rather than use the ? param.  This might tell you if that is where the problem is.. 

BEGIN DELETE FROM CODE_OWNER WHERE CODE_OWNER_ID = 3; END

Comment: I found an alternative solution though time consuming. what i did was using a row-command I deleted them in the vb page and then updated then gridview by calling the bind method.

Comment: I think if we could set the parameters from the vb page, it would work. I don't know how to do it. Have to search and find